# Prove $(1+a^3) (1+b^3)(1+c^3) \ge (\frac{ab+bc+ca+1}{2})^3$

Tags: inequality, cubics

This is a question from 4U maths (highest level of Y12 maths in Australia) from a generally difficult paper. The question itself does not define what a, b, and c are - based on the comments, we assume a, b, c are real and non-negative.

It is suggested, but not required, to use the following (already proven in earlier part) identity:
$a^3+b^3+c^3\ge3abc$

I have tried various ways to solve this, including moving everything to one side and proving that it must be positive, and using AM $\ge$ GM scenarios, as well as multiple applications/substitutions of the proved identity, but did not come up with a valid solution.

I have seen the solution, which uses the identity proved 4 times, substituting a,b,c with variations of $(\frac{a^3}{1+a^3})^\frac{1}{3}, (\frac{b^3}{1+b^3})^\frac{1}{3}, (\frac{c^3}{1+c^3})^\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{(1+a^3)^\frac{1}{3}}$ etc. and working from there (summing and algebra) to reach the required result.

I would like to know if that is any other way we can reach the required result other than the method used by the solution.

Comment: I am a bit confused because the inequality $a^3+b^3+c^3\geq 3abc$ does not hold in general. For example, set $a=-1$, $b=c=0$. This inequality does hold when $a, b, c$ are nonnegative (due to AM-GM inequality). So, I am wondering whether the inequality you're asking is also about the case when $a, b, c$ are all non-negative? By the way, we can also take the cube root of both sides, and instead try to prove $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \geq (ab+bc+ca+1)/2$ which seems simpler.

Comment: Re my previous comment: When $a, b, c$ are non-negative, the given inequality is indeed easy: after expanding $2(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$ we get enough terms to dominate $ab+bc+ca+1$. So... perhaps the original hypothesis is indeed that $a, b, c$ are real (and not necessarily positive reals).

Comment: I don't know - the question does not specify. However, given the comments received and noting it does not appear to hold when negative numbers are allowed, I've modified the definition of a, b, and c accordingly. The original (source) question itself gives no guidance.

Comment: I realise I made a mistake in typing out the question, and have edited accordingly. So it is not possible to take the cube root of both sides and obtain a simpler expression (as you could when the incorrect question was typed. Sorry for the confusion. It does still appear a,b,c need to be non-negative real as the counterexample still would mean the inequality would not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original: This is not an answer. I do not have enough reputation to comment so I leave it here.

Is there any typo in the problem? If no, this inequality is not correct in general. For example take $a=-1,b=c=3$. Then $LHS=0$ and $RHS=8$. Note that this counterexample shows $(1+a^3)(1+b^3)(1+c^3)\geq\frac{(ab+bc+ca+1)^3}{8}\cdots(*)$ is not true. I guess maybe the right question is to prove (*) for $a,b,c\geq0$?

---

Edit:

If the question is $(1+a)^3(1+b)^3(1+c)^3\geq\frac{(ab+bc+ca+1)^3}{8}$, then Prism's comment already solves this problem. It is clear that the equality never holds under the condition $a,b,c\geq 0$.

Now we prove (*). We will use $\sum$ to denote the cyclic sum, i.e.
$$\sum f(a,b,c):=f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b).$$
By direct calculation it is equivalent to show
$$8(1+\sum a^3+\sum a^3b^3+a^3b^3c^3)\geq(\sum ab)^3+3(\sum ab)^2+3(\sum ab)+1.$$
One can check that (by direct calculation again)
$$\begin{aligned}RHS&=\sum a^3b^3+3\sum ab(a^2c^2+b^2c^2)+6a^2b^2c^2+3\sum a^2b^2+3\sum ab(ac+bc)+3\sum ab+1\\
&=\sum a^3b^3+3abc\sum ab(a+b)+6a^2b^2c^2+3\sum a^2b^2+6abc\sum a+3\sum ab+1\end{aligned}.$$
Now we have

(1) $2\sum a^3b^3+3=\sum (a^3b^3+a^3b^3+1)\geq\sum 3a^2b^2$ by AM-GM.

(2) $6(abc)^3+2\sum a^3b^3+2\sum a^3\geq3abc\sum ab(a+b)$ because:

$\;\;\;$(2a) $\sum((abc)^3+a^3b^3+a^3)\geq\sum(3abc\cdot a^2b)$ by AM-GM.

$\;\;\;$(2b) $\sum((abc)^3+a^3b^3+b^3)\geq\sum(3abc\cdot ab^2)$ by AM-GM.

(3) $2\sum a^3b^3+4\sum a^3\geq 6abc\sum a$ because.

$\;\;\;$(3a) $\sum(a^3b^3+a^3+c^3)\geq\sum(3abc\cdot a)$ by AM-GM.

$\;\;\;$(3b) $\sum(a^3b^3+b^3+c^3)\geq\sum(3abc\cdot b)$ by AM-GM.

(4) $\sum(a^3b^3)\geq 3a^2b^2c^2$ by AM-GM.

(5) $2(abc)^3+1\geq3a^2b^2c^2$ by AM-GM.

(6) $2\sum a^3+3=\sum(a^3+b^3+1)\geq 3\sum ab$ by AM-GM.

Taking the sum of (1) to (6) gives us the desired inequality. One can see that the equality holds if and only if $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: Sorry, the question has been edited - I realised I originally made a typo in the placement of the cubes on the LHS.

Comment: You can check my proof for the edited problem :).

Comment: To be honest, still trying to understand/work through your proof. It is quite hefty and substantial :).

Comment: To be honest, your answer is a bit too involved for me to follow. But accepting it as the answer as you're confident it's correct and currently no alternatives. Guess there must not be many ways to do this question.